# How to Split HTML and Elements Sections Horizontally in Safari Dev Tools

Tags: macos, safari, devtools

I am experiencing a strange issue with Safari Dev Tools.

Safari does not allow me to split the HTML section and the Styles section horizontally, or at least I cannot find an option to do so.

I need to split them horizontally, so that the HTML is at the top and CSS is at the bottom (which is possible in Firefox, Chrome, and other modern browsers) in order to work on a smaller screen, such as a MacBook.

Currently, the HTML section is too small to see anything unless I toggle the "Styles" section back and forth. [Please refer to this video for more details](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OjAWWarQgBd9a1iQOj35JX2aPj3ytxoU/view?usp=sharing) - it appears that I am unable to resize the "Styles" section as well.

Is this normal?

I have tried using the latest "Safari Technology Preview," but the problem persists.

I tried looking in Safari settings and searched the web too but haven't found anything helpful.